# Termux: API 'termux-torch on' doesn't work

Tags: termux

I have installed termux API from the Google Play store and in the termux app with `pkg install termux-api` on my Nokia 2.3 (Android 10) but when I try a simple command like `termux-torch on`, it just "hangs" there and does nothing.
Anything I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1st: use 'pkg' not "apt"

```
pkg update
pkg upgrade
pkg install termux-api
```

run:
For on:  **termux-torch on** 
For off: **termux-torch off**

Answer (score 0):

Download
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.api
And give it all permission

Answer (score 0):

here is the fulfilled solution to your problem!

1. Make sure you have the f-droid version of termux installed on your device because the playstore version of this app has been stopped their updates and closed some of their reposetries. That's why you can't do anything more than basics on that version of application.
2. Make sure you have installed  the termux API(application form) from playstore or any other source. The command
   pkg install termux-api
   Just install the API handler which termux needs to connect with the API application, but you must need to install the termux API application install first.
3. After installing the API give it all the permission.
   Hope it'll help you to fix your problem. Happy coding ; )

Answer (score 0):

**Download** the Termux API on Fdroid, then install with the command:

```
pkg install termux-api
```

and then type:

```
termux-torch on.. enj
```

Comment: I've attempted to add formatting to your post. However, as this isn't my area of expertise, I may not have correctly interpreted what should be code. Please review my edits and, if appropriate, [edit] your answer to correct any formatting mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

It's just that the team is not updating termux in playstore. They have an updated version in [FDROID APP](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/). So you have to download fdroid. Go to appstore, then download the termux from there and you're good to go.